# In a Laravel Eloquent model, do we call table field names using camelCase, even though they contain an underscore in the db?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In the database let's say I have in my user's table these fields: `name`, `favorite_color`, `created_at`, etc...

Using Eloquent to save:

## 1:

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = "John";
$user->favorite_color = 'blue';  // Notice the underscore
$user->save();
```

## 2:

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = "John";
$user->favoriteColor = 'blue';  // camelCase
$user->save();
```

Which one of the above is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one is the correct form. But there's a package to help you do the second one: https://github.com/kirkbushell/eloquence.

Comment: Because of Laraval (and PSR-4), I've committed to camelCase...but I was surprised still how inconsistent things are. This being one example. But then there is css (which uses dashes), sql (uses underscores), assoc. array indexes that represent data retrieved from db (which I'm persuaded to use underscores to keep them matching the actual database fields), URL query parameters and form element names...ARGHHH! But thank you, :-) I can accept the answer as soon as the time limit is over.

Comment: @DavidGraham you mean PSR-1 i guess, psr-4 is only for autoloading (numero due)

Comment: I have always used underscores, is camelcase really mandatory for PSR-1?

Comment: @zwacky Yeah I guess so...but PSR-1 wasn't initially enough for me to leave snake_case/underscores. PSR-4, auto-loading, Laravel 4, and composer was enough to make me do it.

Comment: @prograhammer use camelCase for all of your senarios (db,css, ..) set `public static $snakeAttributes = false;` on your base laravel model.