# What's the PSR-2 standard for associative array indexes (and what's the correct naming approach when pulling directly from a query)

Tags: php, laravel-4, standards, associative-array, psr-0

What's the PSR-2 standard for associative array indexes? For consistency I would assume camelCase, however consider a case like this (I'm using Laravel 4+):

```
// In Users table I have fields like this: favorite_color, created_at, etc...
$id = 1;
$rows = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id"),array("id"=>$id));
$row = $rows[0];

return $row;
```

Now `$row` contains array indexes with underscores (snake_case). **What would you do?**

Would you NEVER let array indexes have underscores, doing the extra work needed to format them from the query? Or would you allow this only for instances where you are pulling from the database (perhaps you justify it by saying to yourself *"hey that's an indicator to me that came directly from a query"*)? Also consider that you may have other places in your application that use an index like this: `data['favoriteColor']`. And keep in mind the answer to my other question: [In a Laravel Eloquent model, do we call table field names using camelCase, even though they contain an underscore in the db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274988/in-a-laravel-eloquent-model-do-we-call-table-field-names-using-camelcase-even)

Comment: I don't think PSR-2 addresses it at all.  Consider that associative array keys take many forms besides simple strings which would be conducive to camelCase or snake_case. https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

Comment: Also, a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl` having no column alias will return an array key called `COUNT(*)`, which is totally valid.

Comment: Good point, sometimes I've found even using spaces in the index strings appropriate.

Comment: What if you are throwing that into a view? (php `extract`) Now you've got a problem, since you used snake_case? (of course assuming you've ran your html_entities over it accordingly)

Comment: But maybe I digress here, because if you had spaces in those indexes, you'd still have a problem.

Comment: If you want to adhere to PSR-2, simply install PHP_CodeSniffer and use an editor plugin to analyse your code. It has options to set to most major standards such as PSR and PEAR.

Comment: Ok @MichaelBerkowski maybe convert your response to an answer and perhaps expand a bit on what you typically do when you get `data['favorite_color']` in the spirit of consistency. If nobody chimes in better, I'd happily accept it...as I think you're point is correct.

Comment: @orciny Yeah, just got sublime-linter going yesterday, was considering getting codesniffer as well as I'm making a move from Aptana to Sublime text 3. But would it care about the array indexes?

Comment: @david-graham Probably not as I don't think that's covered in the standard. PHP_CodeSniffer follows the standard set in the config and nothing else. You could always create your own standard and set of rules for PHPCS if the PSR's are too broad for your spec.

Comment: @DavidGraham I don't really feel qualified to answer (which is why I commented) because 1) I don't adhere strictly to PSR-2, generally disagreeing with a lot of it 2) I don't use Laravel 3) this is a little too opinion-based. I would in turn suggest you collect what you've learned from comments and post your own answer to this.

Comment: I think I must have some sort of record of how many of my own questions I've answered. Haha! Ok, sounds good...let's wait and see if any folks go for an answer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I kind of know what you mean about having issues with PSR. I mean, we have to take into consideration that PHP is intermingled with things like CSS (when we place variables in our views) and CSS uses dashes. And PHP works directly with MySQL which uses snake_case. But I suppose PSR won the battle in my world because of Laravel and Composer and the autoloader standard.

Comment: @DavidGraham I happily work with PSR-0,4 autoloaders, and PSR-3 logging when necessary, but only broadly apply PSR-2. I'm unlikely to attach a style enforcer like PHPCS unless I was forced to for community contributions. But I also work in a Drupal shop, where several of Drupal's community style standards fly right in the face of PSR-2